# UITableView cell selected not loading another View

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Hey everbody, im getting a curious problem here. Im trying to make my table push another view, called 'productviewcontroller'.

Im importing both 'productviewcontroller' and  'myappviewcontroller' on header.

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "MyAppViewController.h"
#import "TBXML.h"
#import "ProductViewController.h"
```

And im setting my table to push the another view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ProductViewController *productViewController = [[ProductViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:productViewController animated:YES];
    [productViewController release];

    NSLog(@"Test.");
}
```

When i selects the cell, it gives me the message 'test'. But dont push the another view.
Im setting the navigationController on app delegate.

What im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks right. Does the ProductView nib include a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes. But i dont know if its correct. Should i declare it on header? UINavigationController *navBarController; ? Thanks!

Comment: As long as there's a navigation controller and a navigation item in your .xib it should work on its own.

Comment: Yeah, its there. I forgot to say im setting a TabBar. So, its a TabBar, which have the view with the table.

Comment: Hey, i found the problem, and was that what you said. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use your navigation controller in this view from which you want to push "ProductControllerView" and bind it with IBOutlet and you are able to push the view..

Comment: No need to add Navigation controller in app delegate

Comment: Yea, but the problem is in this view i already have a UITableView. How can i set a Navigation Controller in TableView?